# Haskll, height balanced check

Tags: haskell, height, binary-search-tree, tree-balancing

Is there a way to convert this, so that it checks for balance based on height? (Assuming this is what the problem is.)

```
size :: Tree a -> Int
size (Leaf n)    = 1
size (Node x z) = size x + size z + 1

isBalanced :: Tree a -> Bool
isBalanced (Leaf _) = True
isBalanced (Node l r) = 
    let diff = abs (size l - size r) in
    diff <= 1 && isBalanced l && isBalanced r
```

For example:

```
isBalanced (Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3)) (Leaf 2)) )  = True (Currently returns False)
isBalanced (Node (Node (Leaf 1)(Node (Leaf 1)(Leaf 3))) (Leaf 2))) = False
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `size` counts the total number of nodes. If you want to compute the (maximum) height instead, you want something like this:

```
height :: Tree x -> Int
height (Leaf _) = 1
height (Node x y) = 1 + (height x `max` height y)
```

If you just replace `size` with `height`, the `isBalanced` code should work as before.

Whether this fixes your *problem* remains to be seen, of course...